# Save and Load Int Arrays

Tags: android, arrays, save

I want to save two Int Arrays to a File, so i can load the Int Arrays back in my App after it got closed.
My two Arrays are:

```
    LvlDone[currentLevel - 1] = 1;
    LvlBest[currentLevel - 1] = turnCounter;
```

Comment: use array in xml

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save the int array in the shared preferences (by converting them into a string):

Put your integers into a string, delimiting every int by a character and then save them as a string:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < LvlDone.length; i++) {
    str.append(LvlDone[i]).append(",");
}
prefs.edit().putString("string", str.toString());
```

Get the string and parse it using StringTokenizer:

```
String savedString = prefs.getString("string", "");
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(savedString, ",");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    LvlDone[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}
```

Comment: How can I load the File on Startup? Because at the Moment i get a java.util.NoSuchElementException error